# How to add a column after ordering a data table?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a question about the following code:

```
Den[n_,l_,m_]:=(Sqrt[(2/n)^3*(n-l-1)!/(2*n*(n+l)!)]*Exp[-r/n]*((2*r/n)^l)*LaguerreL[n-l-1,2*l+1,2*r/n]*SphericalHarmonicY[l,m,theta,phi])*Conjugate[Sqrt[(2/n)^3*(n-l-1)!/(2*n*(n+l)!)]*Exp[-r/n]*((2*r/n)^l)*LaguerreL[n-l-1,2*l+1,2*r/n]*SphericalHarmonicY[l,m,theta,phi]]
       shan[n_,l_,m_]:=-NIntegrate[Den[n,l,m]*Log[Den[n,l,m]]*Sin[theta]*r^2,{r,0,Infinity},{theta,0,Pi},{phi,0,2*Pi}]

Ciclo=Table[{n,l,m,shan[n,l,m]},{n,1,2},{l,0,n-1},{m,0,l}]

(* {{{{1,0,0,4.14473}}},{{{2,0,0,8.11093}},{{2,1,0,7.2649},{2,1,1,7.57175+0. I}}}} *)

Tabla=TableForm[SortBy[Flatten[Chop[Ciclo],2],#[[2]]&&#[[1]]&]]


1  0  0  4.14473
2  0  0  8.11093
2  1  0  7.2649
2  1  1  7.57175

Export["sumas.xlsx",Tabla,"XLSX"];
```

My question is: how can I add a column after sorting my data (SortBy)? Something like this:

```
1  1  0  0  4.14473
2  2  0  0  8.11093
3  2  1  0  7.2649
4  2  1  1  7.57175
```

I wanted to add that column and then plot the data with a ListLinePlot.

Note: The SortBy is important, because I actually work with many "n" values. Here I put an example with only 2 values of "n", so as not to copy a huge list of data.

Comment: See Join command documentacion is useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work if you just want to add a column at the beginning or at the end (in this case just reverse the arguments of `Join`):

```
Join[{#} & /@ Range[4], Tabla, 2]

1 1 0 0 4.144729893771763
2 2 0 0 8.110929417877866
3 2 1 0 7.264898399958045
4 2 1 1 7.571750374855915
```